# Substitute Models from MVC with existing Data and/or Business Layer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-access-layer, business-logic-layer

The thing is that i would like to transfer some of our small WinForms applications to ASP.NET

I have the Data Access Layer dlls and the Business Layer Dlls.

Is it a good practice to substitute the models with these dlls and use Controllers and Views to create the MVC apps?

Or i should recreate somwhow my layers to facilitate for MVC programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC is just a pattern, and ASP.NET is fairly loosely coupled in that respect. The DAL is handled by Entity Framework and the Views by Razor by default, but you can substitute these out. In particular with the model layer, some people prefer to use something like NHibernate instead of Entity Framework. It's therefore, equally okay to use your own DAL.